# Shopify link to tag on home page

Tags: shopify, liquid

Hi Im trying to include links to a collections tags on the home page of my site using link_to_tag. this works fine when on a collection page but doesnt seem to work on the home page instead of giving the url collection/tag-handle  it gives homepage/?constraint=tag-handle

any idea how I can achieve this? would rather not require people to have to create a collection for each tag and link to that

brief summary of how I am approaching this:

```
{% if link.type == 'collection_link' %}
 {% assign collection = link.object %}
   <ul class="site-nav__dropdown">
   {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
    <li>
     {{ tag | link_to_tag: tag }}
    </li>
   {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the collection name, you can place the collection in anywhere of store.

I used this:

```
{% assign collection = collections['your-collection-handle'] %}
  <ul class="">
   {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ tag | handleize | prepend:'/' | within: collection }}">{{ tag }}</a>
    </li>
   {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a kind of solution that seems to work for collection pages and non collection pages..... but it seems quite hacky. and I dont know if there are any downsides to this?

```
<a href="{{ link.url }}/{{tag | handle}}">{{tag}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For tag names with a url to all products with that specific tag you can use the following:

```
{% for tag in collection.tags %}
   {% assign tag_url = tag | handleize | prepend: '/' | prepend: routes.all_products_collection_url %}
   {{ tag | link_to: tag_url }}
{% endfor %}
```

This works also on product tags if you like to use it on a product card for example.

```
{% for tag in product.tags %}
   {% assign tag_url = tag | handleize | prepend: '/' | prepend: routes.all_products_collection_url %}
   {{ tag | link_to: tag_url }}
{% endfor %}
```